# Getting this error 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Trying to set up a new field in the dataframe using below code:

```
df_state['pro_per_clm']=df_state.groupby('individual_id').apply(df_state['product_after']/df_state['claims_after'])
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it can help you get started. I had to make some assumptions on what you want, but make sure your fields are numeric types.

```
def pro(df_state):
    pro_per_clm = df_state['product_after'].sum() / df_state['claims_after'].sum()
    return pd.Series({'pro_per_clm':pro_per_clm})

series =  df_state.groupby('individual_id').apply(pro).squeeze()
df_state['pro_per_clm'] = df_state['individual_id'].map(series)
```